# Php type/css file not working as it should

Tags: php, html, css

This is my code

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
// Admin Color Define //
$admint = "Admin";
$admincolor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shout_titles WHERE title = '".$admint."'");
$gac = mysql_fetch_array($admincolor);

// Co-Admin Color Define //
$cadmint = "Co-Admin";
$cacolor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shout_titles WHERE title = '".$cadmint."'");
$gcac = mysql_fetch_array($cacolor);

// Moderator Color Define //
$modt = "Moderator";
$modcolor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shout_titles WHERE title = '".$modt."'");
$gmodc = mysql_fetch_array($modcolor);

// Banned Color Define //
$bannedt = "Banned";
$bancolor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shout_titles WHERE title = '".$bannedt."'");
$gbanc = mysql_fetch_array($bancolor);

// New Color Define //

?>
div#shoutbox {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #000000;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}
a{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.bgOn, .bgOff {
    padding: 2px;
}
.bgOn {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
.bgOn a {
    color: #000000;
}
.bgOff {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    color: #000000;
}
.bgOff a {
    color: #000000;
}
.date {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 80%;
}
.delete, a.delete {
  color: #F00;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ban, a.ban {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.group<?=$admint?> .title {
    color: <?=$gac['color']?>;
}
.group<?=$modt?> .title {
    color: <?=$gmodc['color']?>;
}
.group<?=$cadmin?> .title {
    color: <?=$gcac['color']?>;
}
.group<?=$banned?> .title {
    color: <?=$gbanc['color']?>;
}
```

This is how I have the call
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="shoutbox.php" media="screen">`

the code `div#shoutbox` and all of the classes starting with `group` are not working. Everything else works fine.

Here is the output I get.

[image: Css Output]

This is the first time I have written a style sheet with php, its not that much different so I am not sure why it's not working.

It is probably something silly that I have missed but I cannot identify it.

Comment: check if short tags are enabled on php.ini. try: "<?php echo $css?>", instead

Comment: Please show output of CSS file.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump` on the variables? Like `$gac` `$admint` etc. Because if the query fails it returns false, and printing false shows nothing.

Comment: Perhaps a little off topic here, but I would strongly recommend using the mysql_real_escape_string() method to escape your input values.
php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
EDIT: This is, when the variables come from user input.

Comment: Can you please show output of rendered CSS file.

Comment: @KingKongFrog thank you for asking for this because when I looked at it I found the error, I listed the wrong variables for banned and co-admin, if you would like to post this as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your rendered CSS File and see if there are any issues and/or paste it here :)